# Re-arrange Cortana's glance items

Tags: cortana

I love Cortana's at-a-glance thing, but she seems to assume which ones I want at the top. I care more about the weather than the top headlines. Sorry for the large images:

See here, she's got news near the top:

[image: Top]

And weather at the bottom:

[image: Bottom]

I want weather on top and news on the bottom.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Unfortunately this isn't editable since Cortana manages news/weather etc. But maybe if it'll go out of beta you will be  able to edit this by yourself. By now, it's possible that Cortana will change this by herself, give her some time.